# Get user_data of a aws instance using AWS::EC2::Instance class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

I want to get the user_data of a ec2 instance from that instance. I looked at documentation of class   AWS::EC2::Instance at the link 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/EC2/Instance.html

and tried getting user_data like this

require 'aws-sdk'
puts AWS::EC2::Instance.instance.user_data

But I think this is not the right way it works . Can any one let me know how to get user_data of a instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
require 'aws-sdk'

EC2 = AWS::EC2.new(
 :access_key_id => 'access_key_id',
 :secret_access_key => 'secret_access_key')

instance = EC2.instances['i-9e516a95']
puts instance.user_data
```

**Note**:- 'i-9e516a95' is a particular instance_id and make sure that this instance is running.

Comment: I am running it from the ec2 instance itself and I want to know the user_data of this instance only.. On giving the instance id it gives error    "The instance ID  does not exist (AWS::EC2::Errors::InvalidInstanceID::NotFound). "

Comment: Ya I have given the instance id from the console.aws.amazon.com only .. but that doesn't seem to work. :(

Comment: is that instance running ?

Comment: yup I am executing this code from that instance itself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53902/discussion-between-shamsul-haque-and-user1788294)